# Connecting React Front-End with API

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, multipartform-data, mern

iam facing some issue with connecting my API with my front-end application. The API is used to upload csv file's content to a MongoDB collection. To do this, I made a simple form that asks for a csv file, but i cant figure out how to upload this file to the server where my api can act on it and store it in Mongodb.

This is the API's controller file:

```
var Stds = require('../models/stds')
var csv = require('csvtojson')

const importStds = async(req,res)=>{
    try{

        var stdsData = [];

        csv()
        .fromFile(req.file.path)
        .then(async(response) => {
            for(var x = 0; x < response.length; x++){
                stdsData.push({
                    enNo: response[x].EnNo,
                    name: response[x].Name,
                    sec: response[x].Sec,
                })
            }
        })
        await Stds.insertMany(stdsData)
        res.send({status:200, success: true, msg:'Imported'})
    } catch(error) {
        res.send({status:400, success: false, msg:error.message})
    }
}

module.exports = importStds
```

This is its Route file:

```
var express = require('express')
const stds = express()
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

stds.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
stds.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'public')))
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb) =>{
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage:storage})

const stdsController = require('../controllers/stdsC')

stds.post('/importStds', function(req,res) {stdsController.importStds})

module.exports = stds;
```

This is how I have called it in backend index.js file:

```
var stdsRoute = require('./routes/stdsR')
app.use('/', stdsRoute)
```

This is the form:

```
<div id="batchfield">
                <label for="bfile">Upload Student Info:</label>
                <input type="file" name="bfile" id="bfile" accept=".csv"></input>
                <div className="button" onClick={() => subBatch({})}>Submit</div>
</div>
```

This is the function i tried to use to upload my file.

```
const subBatch =() => {
        const batch = document.getElementById("bfile")
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append("csv-file", batch)
        axios.post("http://localhost:9002/stdsRoute", data)
            .then(res => {
                alert(res.data.message)
            })
    }
```

Iam a beginner so i dont really know what iam doing, would appretiate any help

Comment: Your question lacks details neccessary to point you to a right direction. Maybe there is an issue on your API side. But at least one thing you could try to change is the `asios` call. Browsers doesn't have axios built-in so try replacing it with `fetch`. Also you could press F12 to open debug tools in your browser. Try checking console logs as well as "Network" tab to debug what is going on with your front-end

Comment: @JSEvgeny thank you for your suggestion, i have updated the question. In console's network tab it shows error 404 and ERR_BAD_REQUEST

Comment: As you have '/importStds' as an endpoint point, you have to provide full path to it when calling it from your front-end, so your API call should look something like this `axios.post("http://localhost:9002/importStds", data)`. This should possibly fix an issue with 404 - meaning not found, because your API endpoint was different from what you've pointed to with your axios call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JSEvgeny, your issue lies with you call to the API.

Particularly, this line:

> ```js
> axios.post("http://localhost:9002/stdsRoute", data)
> ```

Your endpoint is named in this line:

> ```js
> stds.post('/importStds', function(req,res) {stdsController.importStds})
> ```

which means that the former should be switched to:

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:9002/importStds", data)
```

in order to properly call the API endpoint.